# Most performant way to inherit structs in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, class, struct, unions

Let's say I have the following:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)

struct HDR {
   unsigned short msgType;
   unsigned short msgLen;
};

struct Msg1 {
   unsigned short msgType;
   unsigned short msgLen;
   char text[20];
};

struct Msg2 {
   unsigned short msgType;
   unsigned short msgLen;
   uint32_t c1;
   uint32_t c2;
};

 .
 .
 .
```

I want to be able to reuse the HDR struct so I don't have to keep defining the two members: msgType and msgLen.  I don't want to involve vtables for performance reasons but I do want to override operator<< for each of the structs.  Based on this last requirement, I don't see how I could possibly use a union since the sizes are also different.

Any ideas on how this can best be handled for pure performance

Comment: Isn't `operator<<()` used mostly for working with *text* streams, not binary streams?

Comment: Just overload the operator instead.

Comment: @Karmastan: Pretty much never, I'd imagine. It is, however, useful for writing into them.

Comment: @user:  Please heed @Oli's advice below.  If you are defining structs for processing messages, you don't want inheritance, but composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern to deal with binary network protocols is define a struct that contains an union:

```
struct Message {
   Header hdr;
   union {
      Body1 msg1;
      Body2 msg2;
      Body3 msg3;
   };
};
```

Semantically you are stating that a `Message` is composed of a `Header` and a body that can be one-of `Body1`, `Body2`... Now, provide insertion and extraction operators for the header and each body separately. Then implement the same operators for the `Message` by calling it on the `Header`, and depending on the message type, the body of the message that makes sense.

Note that the elements of the union do not need to have the same size. The size of the union will be the maximum of it's members' sizes. This approach allows for a compact binary representation that can be read/written from the network. Your read/write buffer will be the `Message` and you will read just the header and then the appropriate body.

```
// Define operators:
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, Header const & );
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, Body1 const & ); // and the rest
// Message operator in terms of the others 
std::ostream& opeartor<<( std::ostream& o, Message const & m )
{
   o << m.header;
   switch ( m.header.type ) {
   case TYPE1: o << m.body1; break;
   //...
   };
   return o;
}

// read and dump the contents to stdout
Message message;
read( socket, &message, sizeof message.header );   // swap the endianness, check size...
read( socket &message.msg1, message.header.size ); // ...
std::cout << message << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 10):

Composition seems most appropriate here:

```
struct Msg1
{
    HDR hdr;
    char text[20];
};
```

Whilst you could use C++ inheritance, it doesn't really make sense semantically in this case; a `Msg1` is not a `HDR`.

Alternatively (and possibly preferentially), you could define an abstract `Msg` base type:

```
struct Msg
{
    HDR hdr;
protected:
    Msg() {}
};
```

and have all your concrete message classes derive from that.

Answer (score 8):

What is wrong with normal C++ inheritance?

```
struct HDR { ... };
struct Msg1: HDR { ... };
```

Just don't declare any virtual member functions and you'll be all set.

Comment: +1. The myth that you need to make things polymorphic in order to use inheritance in C++ seems to be getting more and more prevalent; god only knows why.

Comment: This obviously works, but I'd argue that it doesn't make as much sense as composition, semantically speaking.  A `Msg1` is not a `HDR`.

Comment: True, but when I have to choose between simplicity and semantic zealotry, I tend to pick the simplicity. That's my opinion though, both options work.

Comment: If you renamed `HDR` to `Msg` then you'd have an IS-A relationship. (a `Msg1` is a `Msg`)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're planning on doing with these structs, you can do this without incurring any vtable overhead like this:

```
struct HDR {
   unsigned short msgType;
   unsigned short msgLen;
};

struct Msg1: HDR {
   char text[20];
   friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Msg1& msg);
};

struct Msg2: HDR {
   uint32_t c1;
   uint32_t c2;
   friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Msg2& msg);
};
```

Since the base class does not have any virtual functions in it, you won't get a vtable for these objects.  However, you should be aware that this means that if you have a `HDR` pointer pointing at an arbitrary subclass, you won't be able to print it out, since it won't be clear which `operator<<` function to call.

I think, though, that there could be a more fundamental issue here.  If you're trying to treat all of these objects uniformly through a base pointer but want to be able to print them all out, then you're going to have to take a memory hit to tag each object.  You can either tag them implicitly with a vtable, or explicitly by adding your own type information.  There really isn't a good way of getting around this.

If, on the other hand, you just want to simplify your logic by factoring the data members into the base class, then this approach should work.

Comment: Why the apparently unneeded friendship?

Comment: @Noah Roberts- Good point; they could just be free, non-friend functions.  I'm so used to writing these as friends that I just kept it up anyway. :-)

Comment: You should break yourself of that habit ASAP, IMNSHO.  See Myers: http://www.drdobbs.com/184401197